# SQL Server : update multiple columns results in error

Tags: sql-server, triggers, subquery

I've got a query

```
update a
set customer_no = 85002123
from TABLE_DATA a
where customer_no = 80282318
```

Output for the table_data looks as follows

```
Customer_no Season  TextField   ID
--------------------------------------
80282318    2017    TEXT1       48807
80282318    2017    TEXT2       47043
80282318    2017    TEXT3       47631
80282318    2017    TEXT4       48219
80282318    2017    TEXT5       49395
```

and what we want it to be is

```
Customer_no Season  TextField   ID
--------------------------------------
85002123    2017    TEXT1       48807
85002123    2017    TEXT2       47043
85002123    2017    TEXT3       47631
85002123    2017    TEXT4       48219
85002123    2017    TEXT5       49395
```

`Table_data` has a unique `ID` key, that is not customer number.

It has 5 rows for customer_no 80282318, and I want all 5 updated to the new value, unrelated to any other criteria.

(I can't change it based on ID key) because this is just a subset of our data - we have hundreds of rows like this in groups of 2-5 per customer_no. I can't figure out how to run the update script because I keep getting the following error.

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LT_TABLE_DATA_trigger_UPDATE, Line 11
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The trigger on the code says the following:

```
declare @id_key int = (select e.id_key from TABLE_DATA e join inserted i on e.id_key = i.id_key)

update  TABLE_DATA 
set     last_update_dt = GETDATE(),
        last_updated_by = user_name()
where   id_key = @id_key
```

Comment: Its a problem with a trigger on the table.  Show us the trigger code.

Comment: Edited the ticket to have the trigger on there.

Comment: I think you need to share your table structure and the entire trigger. I posted an answer that would be valid based on the details in the question. Here is a great place to look if you are unsure what you should post. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message couldn't be more clear. Your subquery returned more than 1 row. This is a common yet extremely major flaw with triggers. They fire once per operation, not once per row. So if you are updating more than 1 row this will fail.

Try getting rid of that scalar variable and use a set based approach like this.

```
update e
set last_update_dt = GETDATE(),
    last_updated_by = user_name()
from  TABLE_DATA e
join inserted i on e.id_key = i.id_key
```

Comment: I understand the error message, and i see why its happening but generally we want to restrict code to make any kind of changes on the id_key for the field. That said even with the update you state we still are getting the same error

Comment: From the code I posted that error would be impossible. There is no subquery in the code I posted. Perhaps you didn't share all the trigger code? Or maybe there are multiple update triggers on that table?

Comment: There is only one trigger on the table. But the issue was i needed to reconnect to the server and reopen the query. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ALTER  TRIGGER <TriggerName> ON dbo.TABLE_DATA
        AFTER UPDATE
    AS
        BEGIN

            UPDATE  TABLE_DATA
            SET     last_update_dt = GETDATE() ,
                    last_updated_by = USER_NAME()
            WHERE   id_key IN ( SELECT  e.id_key
                                FROM    TABLE_DATA e
                                        JOIN inserted i ON e.id_key = i.id_key )



        END
    GO
```